If two functors preserve a certain colimit and a whiskered natural transformation is an isomorphism then so is the transformation at the colimit
Let $F,G : A \rightrightarrows B$ be two functors and $α : F \Rightarrow G$ a natural transformation.
Let $D : J \to A$ be a functor (a diagram) so that $F$ and $G$ preserve colimits of this sort.
Then if $\alpha\circ D : F ◦ D \Rightarrow G ◦ D$ is an isomorphism, so is $\alpha_{colim D} : F (colim D) \to G(colim D)$.

I see that since
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
colim(F◦D) @>>> colim(G◦D)\\
@V\cong VV @VV\cong V\\
F(colim D) @>>> G(colim D)
\end{CD}
commutes, it's enough to prove that $colim(F◦D) \to colim(G◦D)$ is an isomorphism.
I'm not sure how this helps though.

Does this follow for limits too?
Thanks in advance!

What is your question? Are you asking how to prove the statement in the third sentence?

Hint: all functors preserve isomorphisms.
